# Custom arithmetic filter clause in ORM

Tags: django, django-orm

I am trying to retrieve from a particular table all rows for which a certain subtraction results in a value smaller or equal to a certain fixed value. In SQL it would look like this:

`SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE column_a - column_b <= 1;`

In Django, I thought I could apply a `filter` combining `F` expressions, but as far as I have seen that is only possible if the value to compare against is a column or annotation. Since usage of the the `extra` keyword is discouraged and `RawSQL` is also not an attractive option, I would like to know if there is a built-in way to apply this kind of filtering. Of course I could also do with an annotation, but out of curiosity would be good to know if there is a more 'direct' way.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As you say, you use `annotate`. But that doesn't imply an aggregation, it's just a calculated field. So:

```
MyTable.objects.annotate(calculated_field=F('column_a') - F('column_b')).filter(calculated_field__lte=1)
```

Comment: Yes, I know I can do that, I am asking if there is a way so that the underlying SQL directly translates to the WHERE clause that I mentioned using the ORM abstractions, not with `extra` or `RawSQL`.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking. Why does it matter if the field gets annotated?

Comment: Well, I'm just curious if it is at all possible. I had already the query with an annotation, the question is just if there is a way to define a `WHERE` clause like the one I described using the ORM.